# MYSQL SUM of positive and negative values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column name 'AmountLC' in the db table. Another column name 'DebitCredit' determines whether the 'AmountLC' is Positive or Negative. If DebitCredit="H", the values in AmountLC is Negative. If DebitCredit="S", the values in AmountLC is Positive. I need to make query to get the sum of AmountLC. I have tried to get the logic but didn't get any. I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

I tried the below code as per other stackoverflow discussions.

```
$F7 = mysql_query("SELECT 
                SUM(CASE WHEN DebitCredit='H' THEN DebitCredit ELSE 0 END) as NegativeTotal,
                SUM(CASE WHEN DebitCredit='S' THEN DebitCredit ELSE 0 END) as PostiveTotal 
                FROM T1_CSV_Table 
                WHERE Month='$getMonth' AND TaxCode='A0'");
```

THANKS!
Update Code

```
$F7 = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN DebitCredit='H' THEN AmountLC*-1 ELSE AmountLC END) as Total 
                    FROM T1_CSV_Table 
                    WHERE Month='$getMonth' AND TaxCode='A0'");
    $rowf7 = mysql_fetch_array($F7);
    echo "Total-".$rowf7['Total'];
```

Update code for results:
*SELECT `AmountLC`,`DebitCredit` FROM `T1_CSV_Table` WHERE `TaxCode`="A0" AND Month="12"*

[image]

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Shouldn't `THEN DebitCredit` be `THEN AmountLC`?

Comment: How about `SUM(CASE WHEN DebitCredit='H' THEN AmountLC*-1 ELSE AmountLC END) as Total,`

Comment: yeah, i know it's not a logic. just tried a code. There are no separate positive and negative values. I need to decide depends on the DebitCredi value.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I will try that

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the code as you said. But nothing returns

Comment: Strange, it works for me! What data type is `AmountLC`

Comment: AmountLC is decimal(10,2)

Comment: When you say nothing is returned what do you mean, if the query runs you should get something back even if its not the right number

Comment: Total-array(2) { [0]=> NULL ["Total"]=> NULL }
This is the array I get when I run the query

Comment: When I run the query in the db, I get Total=0.00

Comment: Are you sure you have any values in the DB for this month and TaxCode

Comment: yes, sure. Almost 2lks columns in the table

Comment: Do a test for me, run `SELECT AmountLC, DebitCredit WHERE Month='Hard_code_a_valid_month' AND TaxCode='A0'` and show us a few results

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: I updated the result in the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that calculation all in one go if all you want is a total of the debits and credits

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DebitCredit='H' THEN AmountLC*-1 ELSE AmountLC END) as Total
FROM T1_CSV_Table 
WHERE Month='$getMonth' AND TaxCode='A0'
```

> NOTE: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I am accepting this an answer. I will try to figure it out whats wrong with my code. Thanks for the logic :)

Answer (score -1):

try this please:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(DebitCredit='H', DebitCredit, 0) AS NegativeTotal,
    SUM(IF(DebitCredit='S', DebitCredit, 0) AS PostiveTotal
FROM T1_CSV_Table 
WHERE
    MONTH='$getMonth'
AND
    TaxCode='A0';
```

Comment: I didn't. I am trying this. Thanks

Comment: Why bother, its not easy adding and substracting `H`'s and `S`'s and getting any sort of useful answer

Comment: It mus not. Look at the question again